# opendnp3 python testing master slave

Tags: python, master-slave, opendnp3

Running [this code](https://github.com/sentient-energy/emsw-opendnp3-mirror/blob/master/demos/master-python/master_demo.py) gives me the following error (I don't know how to pass Log Level as argument)

```
 File "master.py", line 85, in main
    stack_manager = opendnp3.StackManager()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opendnp3/pyopendnp3.py", line 2049, in __init__
    this = _pyopendnp3.new_StackManager(*args)
TypeError: new_StackManager() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)
```

The error is in line 85

```
stack_manager = opendnp3.StackManager()
stack_manager.AddTCPv4Client('tcpclient', phys_layer_settings, '127.0.0.1', 4999)
```

Comment: English corrections, pretty formatting, addition of involved lines of code

Comment: actually, i wanted to know exactly what objects i need to give

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem with that method.  Instead use:

```
    stack_manager = opendnp3.StackManager()
    stack_manager.AddTCPClient('tcpclient', phys_layer_settings, '127.0.0.1', 4999)
```

There's not much documentation, but after a ton of digging there was a re-write around a TCPv4 and TCPv6 method and it looks like they were left in a non-working state